# My 2 1/2 year old won't talk on his own And stares into the distance

Tags: toddler, behavior, language-development

He does say things like "mommy" "daddy" "ewww" "Mickey" "owww" and "drink". They're slurred and you have to know what he's saying to understand them. But he won't say anything else on his own. We can get him to say "please" "thank you" "I you"(his version of I love you) and other small words or phrases if we say "luke say..." but most of the time he's a silent child. He just stares off into the distance and is mute like.

I have 3 older kids And 2 never did anything close to this. The 3rd didn't speak at all until she was 3.(she will be 4 next month and now can't be quiet to save her life lol).

Is this normal? Or should I see a Dr for him or What? Thanks

Comment: [Quantitative Checklist for Autism in Toddlers](http://docs.autismresearchcentre.com/tests/QCHAT-10.pdf) (**Cambridge University**)

Answer (score 4):

Hi and welcome to the forum!
This behavior sounds a bit concerning, and you should definitely bring this up with his pediatrician. He may say that it is too early to have him tested and the best thing you can do is provide one-on-one stimulation and try to engage him in a variety of activities ( i.e., play with him, show him toys, do puzzles, shape-sorting activities, read to him, ask him to point to different objects, etc.). Early interventionists can also help and if you live in a county where he can be evaluated and provided with EI therapy, that would probably do him a world of good.  Good luck!

Comment: _He may say that it is too early to have him tested_ I guess that depends on the tests you're thinking of. Testing his hearing abilities should be possible, for example.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this normal?

I don't think so.

> Or should I see a Dr for him?

Yes, definitely. The **Autism Research Centre** at Cambridge University provides a quick 10-question [Quantitative Checklist for Autism in Toddlers](http://docs.autismresearchcentre.com/tests/QCHAT-10.pdf) to help us assess autistic behaviour in children. The 10th question is:

> Does your child stare at nothing with no apparent purpose?

If your son does that many times a day as you describe, there's at least 33% chance he may require a more detailed assessment.